# Is there a way to know what activated QAction?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I have created instance of `QAction` inside `QGraphicsView` child class and connected it to my slot in the same class.

```
QAction *action   = new QAction(tr("New"), this);
action->setObjectName("addStopAction");
action->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::ControlModifier | Qt::Key_N));
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(addNew()));
addAction(action);
```

Slot is a function creating new instance of `QGraphicsItem` on scene assigned to `QGraphicsView`.

```
void MyGraphicsView::addNew() {
    // Insert new item at cursor position
}
```

I also add this action to a `QMenu` which serves as my class context menu.

```
QMenu *contextMenu = new QMenu(this);
contextMenu->addAction(action);
```

Everything works fine. When I press Command/Ctrl + N new item is created at cursor position. But when I right-click and select action from context menu I want new item to be created at menu positon.

I can, of course, do some little hack to flag if SLOT was called after `contextMenuEvent` or something like that, but what I would like to know is:

Is there any way to find out what made `QAction` emit its `triggered()` signal inside connected SLOT? That way I could handle when I should place new item at cursor position and when at context menu position inside SLOT implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use custom data that a QAction object can contain.
You can set it when you create a context menu:

```
void showContextMenu(const QPoint &pos)
{
    ...
    action->setData(pos);
    ...
}
```

And in the `addNew()` function you check if data exists and reset it in the end:

```
void addNew()
{
    QPoint pos;
    QPoint posFromAction = action->data()->toPoint();
    if (posFromAction.isNull())
    {
        pos = QCursor::pos(); ///< pos will be current cursor's position
    }
    else
    {
        pos = posFromAction; ///< pos will be menu's position
    }

    doYourStuffAt(pos)

    action->setData(QPoint()); ///< reset action's data
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you can find out what signal emit inside connected SLOT.

Just use QObject::sender(). In you case:

```
void MyGraphicsView::addNew() {
    QAction* pAction = qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender());
    Q_ASSERT(pAction);
    // do something with pAction
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i managed something similar by connecting the menu to a function like `connect (menu, SIGNAL( triggered(QAction*) ), this, SLOT( menuAction_triggered(QAction*) ));`

when you execute you context menu, the `QMenu::exec(QPoint)` will return you the pointer to the action, so you may not need a extra function/slot for it.

you can check for the name of the action with its text `QAction::text()` or if you have stored your pointers somewhere by comparing the address.

soo long zai

Comment: I did try that. Problem with this approach is that when I activate action from context menu then both SLOTs will be called (th action one and menu one). That way I can set some flag describing that action was triggered with context menu (in context menu triggered(QAction*) handler) and then handle this case (in action triggered() handler), but it can be also do this the same way with `contextMenuEvent`.

Comment: another possible solution could be that you connect your `QAction::trigered(bool)` signal to a slot of your choice. so you dont need to handle what action is triggered or of what sender it was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference self.sender() in the function that is called when by customContextMenuRequested signal.

```
self.tree1.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.menu1pop)  # rightclick menu signal

...

def menu1pop(self, pos):

    widget = self.sender()

    item = widget.itemAt(pos)
    if item is None: return            # only show contextmenu if on an item
    self.setProperty("mywidget", widget)  # pass current widget 
    self.menu1.popup(QCursor.pos())    # show menu at right click cursor position
```

self.sender() will return your widget object and then you can set the widget object inside a property.

Then when your action function is called you can recall the widget object by reading the property.

```
widget = self.property("mywidget")
```

It's a bit of a hack, but a simple and reliable way to know which widget your action was called from.

Answer (score -1):

You MIGHT be able to use QObject::sender() in the slot that receives the call.  Not tried this for actions though.  It's probably a bit uglier than your proposed 'hack' (where you could actually implement that quite nicely with a scoped class).

Comment: I have tried getting this information from QObject::sender() for quite some time, but was unable to find anything that would help me distinguish what activated action.

Comment: No that will not do the job here. The `sender()` only tells you the object instance which originally emitted the signal (always `== action`), not the event source.

Comment: @leemes ah - thought that might be the case, hence having MIGHT in caps in my answer.

Comment: a reply that is only an educated guess should be a comment. -1.