# Is there way to access QAction::data() without using an intermediate QAction group?

Tags: qt, menu

When creating dynamic menus, I often need the associated signal to respond to a particular index value (e.g., a database row identifier associated with that menu item). To do this I seem to need to use the code below, which feels like a hack.

```
QActionGroup *oneOffgroup = new QActionGroup(menu);
QAction *action = new QAction(tr("New text form..."),menu);
action->setData( writingSystem.id() );
oneOffgroup->addAction(action);
connect( oneOffgroup, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(newTextForm(QAction*)) );
submenu->addAction(action);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389058/is-there-a-way-to-know-what-activated-qaction) suggests using the QMenu::triggered(QAction*) signal. That would just mean that I would have to sort out every signal that was sent to that menu, though. (That would be okay in some contexts, not in the one I am currently working on, though.)

Comment: Why you can't just use QAction::data() in newTextForm(QAction*) slot?

Comment: Which part of this scheme feels like a "hack" to you?

Comment: that's a perfectly fine use of setData(), not a hack.

Comment: Milovidov, the question is how to get a signal that includes a QAction* parameter. Jmk and Frank, I know the code is legit, but it seems like a workaround to use QActionGroup for a single action. I thought there might be some more straightforward way to get this behavior.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your code snippet what's going on, but I think I understand your question now. Why don't you just use one `QActionGroup` for all of the dynamic items? The `triggered` signal includes the action that was triggered, so you don't need a separate group for each action.

Comment: Yeah, for this particular example there are menu items going to three types of slot, so that part could more more elegant. If there's not another way to do it, that's fine, I just wanted to check.